# Adding columns to ggplot2 charts

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I've got the following code (using ggplot2) which outputs the table below:

```
ggplot(final,aes(x=final$Players,y=final$AvgPts,ymin=final$min,ymax=final$max)) +
geom_pointrange() + theme_bw() + coord_flip() + 
geom_hline(yintercept = min(final$min)-1,linetype="dotted") + ylab("") + 
xlab("") +geom_text(aes(label=final$AvgPts),hjust=0.5, vjust=-0.8, size=3) + 
ggtitle(paste("2016 Moneyball Average Spreads for ",pos," averaging more than",points)) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(size=10, face="bold"))
```

[image]

What I want to be able to do is add a couple of columns to the right of the table, for example like in a forest plot, the two columns would be:

```
column1<-final$salary/final$AvgPts
column2<-final$sd
```

I would also like to be able to re-order the chart on either of these columns if this is possible.

Is there also a way to reorder the existing chart on final$AvgPts?

final is structured as follows:

```
Gms AvgPts   max   min    sd         Moneyball   Team salary position playing.status                           Players
   (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)             (chr) (fctr)  (dbl)   (fctr)         (fctr)                             (chr)
1      3  92.00   107    81 13.45        Adam Oxley    COL   6100      MID          Start        Adam Oxley, COL, MID, 6100
2      4 107.00   130    88 20.30      Adam Treloar    COL   8500      MID          Start      Adam Treloar, COL, MID, 8500
3      3  97.67   110    91 10.69      Bernie Vince    MEL   7300      MID      Not Named      Bernie Vince, MEL, MID, 7300
4      4  91.00   119    59 28.66        Jack Viney    MEL   6500      MID          Start        Jack Viney, MEL, MID, 6500
5      4 107.50   142    71 33.91      Jack Ziebell     NM   7500      MID          Start       Jack Ziebell, NM, MID, 7500
6      4 101.25   130    68 25.53      Lachie Neale    FRE   8500      MID          Start      Lachie Neale, FRE, MID, 8500
7      4 110.75   143    55 38.40          Nat Fyfe    FRE   8400      MID          Start          Nat Fyfe, FRE, MID, 8400
8      4 102.00   114    86 11.78  Scott Pendlebury    COL   9200      MID          Start  Scott Pendlebury, COL, MID, 9200
9      2 108.00   128    88 28.28 Steele Sidebottom    COL   8500      MID          Start Steele Sidebottom, COL, MID, 8500
10     4 104.75   114    95  8.14      Taylor Adams    COL   8000      MID          Start      Taylor Adams, COL, MID, 8000
```

Comment: You can use `reorder()` in `aes(y=reorder(x,y)` where x is the dataframe and y is the factor for ordering criteria. It would be helpful to see how that `final` is constructed.

Comment: I've updated the question with the structure of `final`

Answer (score 1):

To add other plots, there are two solutions:

- With `ggplot2`, use the function `facet_wrap`
- With library `griExtra` : `grid.arrange` can create multiple ggplots.

On the specific code to reorder, the easiest way is to re-order the factor levels.

```
final$Players<-factor(final$Players, levels = unique(final$Players)[order_vector])
```

Furthermore, in `aes ggplot` only the name of the column should be passed not the vector item. For example, you can rewrite:

```
ggplot(data = final,aes(x=Players,y=AvgPts,ymin=min,ymax=max))
```

### Edit

#### Ordering the vector

I suppose you want to order on the mean of each player.

```
Mean<-sapply(unique(final$Players),function(z){
   mean(final$AvgPoints[as.character(final$Players) == as.character(z)),]
   }
   )
final$Players<-factor(final$Players, levels = unique(final$Players)[order(Mean)])
```

#### Add a table to the side of the graph with gridExtra

```
library(gridExtra)
g1<-ggplot(final,aes(x=Players,AvgPts,ymin=min,ymax = max)) + ...
g2<-tableGrob(head(final[,c("salary",sd)]))
grid.arrange(g1,g2, ncol=1)
```

More information on `ggplot` and `gridExtra` can be found here : https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Mixing-ggplot2-graphs-with-other-graphical-output

Comment: the 'facet_wrap' function is for separate plots, I'm not specifically wanting to plot column1 and column2, but have them listed like in a forest plot. For example see columns in the following link [link](http://www.cebi.ox.ac.uk/for-practitioners/what-is-good-evidence/how-to-read-a-forest-plot.html)

Comment: With regards to the factor function, would I substitute 'final$AvgPts' for 'order_vector' in your suggestion, ie 'final$Players<-factor(final$Players, levels = unique(final$Players)[final$AvgPts])'. I've tried this and can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: So you would like to add another line according to the link, not another column. I'm correcting the code to answer both you questions.

Comment: Thanks, I've made a small edit to the"Ordering the vector" code so that it worked.

Comment: g2 in the tableGrob formula produces a table with a different number of rows, however, I think what I'm going to do is use the grid.arrange recommended and just combine charts instead of columns, it looks neater. Thanks for the help.